# LibGDX: Changing component inside group, inside a table, causes black square on Android

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

I have a table which contains a row of Powerups, and another Button to 'Watch and Earn' a free powerup.

Each Powerup extends `Group` and contains an ImageButton and some other components.

When tapping on the `Watch and Earn` button, the player is sent to a video ad, and upon returning a Powerup is randomly selected.

My code re-lays-out the Powerup Group to show which one was randomly selected (The ImageButton is recreated and readded with a new background and icon), and to remove the other components that aren't necessary.

On the desktop version this happens without any issue. However when I run the game on my Android device the Powerup Group that is selected just turns black.

Before Ad:
[image: Before Ad]

After Ad:
[image: After Ad]

I've tried calling `invalidate` and `invalidateHierarchy` on the table, and `setActor` on the outer `Cell`.

Note that I do need to invalidate the table because the size of the Powerup Group changes so I need the table to relayout itself.

Comment: I think this may have something to do with the activity being resumed? If I remove the video ad and just do the random pick business, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it by pre-loading all states and switching to them.

For anyone interested, the black square is related to [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets#creating-an-assetmanager) and "black/missing" assets. I am using AssetManager, and I followed the advice given in the above [documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets#resuming-with-a-loading-screen) and swapped out the AssetManager for a new one using `Texture.setAssetManager()`, however, this doesn't solve the issue.

I know that the OpenGL context is lost when the activity is switched over to the Ad, however it seems the new AssetManager still didn't load the asset if it wasn't pre-loaded before the Ad was shown.